# MySQL: how to combine three tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with persons (personid,name), another table with camps (campid,title) and a third table with camp participations (id,personid,campid).

Now, for a given camp, I need a list of all *other* camp participations by all persons participating in the current camp.

But I have no idea how to join these tables. I have looked at a lot of other examples, but I can't really seem to get any inspiration from those...

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers, which I unfortunately can't seem to make work. I simplified the situation a bit in my question, in order for you to understand my problem easier - in the end, it made your answers to me harder for me to understand - for this, I apologize.  

In reality, the unique key in all three tables is just called "id" - this was probably a bad decision. I can't paste the code, which currently works, as it's too long. Hm, I'll see, what I can do...

Comment: Ok - I've pasted the code on http://pastebin.com/RZJfCSrP. As you can see, it takes four SQL calls to make the list I want.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSONS AS D INNER JOIN CAMP_PARTICIPATIONS AS E ON D.PERSONID = E.PERSONID
                  INNER JOIN CAMPS AS F ON F.CAMPID = E.CAMPID
WHERE F.CAMPID <> [your_camp]  AND A.PERSONID IN (

SELECT A.PERSONID
FROM PERSONS AS A INNER JOIN CAMP_PARTICIPATIONS AS B ON A.PERSONID = B.PERSONID
                  INNER JOIN CAMPS AS C ON C.CAMPID = B.CAMPID
WHERE C.CAMPID = [your_camp] )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select persons.*,participations.*,camps.* from persons left join participations 
on participations.personid=persons.personid
left join camps on camps.campid=participations.campid
where camp.campid=1;
```

now u can change the campid in where clause and place column name which u want in select clause